# Macchanger set address resets to permanent MAC address after connected to a network

Tags: networking, network-manager, mac, cinnamon, mint

Every time I set the MAC address, whether to a custom or random one and connect to a network it automatically gets reverted back to the permanent MAC address. If I try adding a "Cloned MAC address" in the network manager the "Save" prompt becomes unavailable so I had no luck so far.
One example of the commands I used for macchanger:

```
$ sudo su
$ ifconfig [INTERFACE] down
$ macchanger --mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX [INTERFACE]
$ ifconfig [INTERFACE] up
```

I'm running Linux Mint 18 Sarah Cinnamon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my Broadcom wireless adapter which wouldn't allow overriding the MAC address and going online with it by default which is a problem I've noticed a bunch of people having. I got an Alfa AWUS036ACS adapter and the macchanger set MAC address doesn't revert to the physical one when I connect to a network with it.